# How to detect network is disconnected in Angular 2+

Tags: error-handling, angular2-routing

I try to find network disconnected issue. I have tried multiple ways. Still i didn't get the solution. I could not achieve with status code.

Here is my sample code:

```
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token); 

    this.http.get('http://someurl/'+userId,{headers:headers})

    .map(res => res.json())

    .subscribe(
      data => {
      console.log(data);
     },

    error => {
      console.log(error);
      if(error.status == 500) {
        this.dashResponse = false;
        this.notFoundResponse = false;
        this.serverErrorResponse = true;
      }
      else if(error.status == 404)
      {
        this.dashResponse = false;
        this.notFoundResponse = true;
        this.serverErrorResponse = false;
      }
      else if(error.status == 401)
      {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        alert('Un Authorized');
        this.refresh();
      }
      else
      {
        this.dashResponse = false;
        this.notFoundResponse = false;
        this.serverErrorResponse = true;
      }
    }

     );
```

Can any one solve my problem ?. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the solution for my Question.

Here is the solution:

1. Import HostListener

   ```
    import { Component, OnInit, HostListener,OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
   ```
2. Put this code in to your AppComponent

   ```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy  {

    //Offline Event
    @HostListener('window:offline', ['$event'])
    OfflineEvent(event: Event) { 

     console.log(event);
      //do something.....
    }

    //Online event
    @HostListener('window:online', ['$event'])
    OnlineEvent(event: Event) {

      console.log(event);
      //do something.....

      }

     }
   ```

You can display whatever you want to show using HostListener.